# Take full localhost webpage screenshot (Firefox, Windows)?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, localhost, screenshot

I need to take a full screenshot of a localhost page I'm working on. Print Screen button offers me no solution to this nor the Alt-Print Screen does, as they take only what is displayed on the screen. I need the shot of the full page.

I tried with some online services and a couple of add-ons for Firefox to no avail since they cannot reach any localhost addess or are not compatible with FF 29.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: This is off-topic, since it doesn't relate to a programming question.

Comment: But FYI, Alt-PrintScrn will capture only the window with focus (FF).

Comment: I need the shot of the full page. Both PrntScr and Alt+PrntScr are limited to what is on the screen. Can you provide a way to programmatically do this, if it's not possible via a more simple action? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll answer my own question.

Forget about add-ons. You can do it via the browser's built-in Developer's Toolbar commands.

1. Press Shift+F2 and to bring the toolbar up at the bottom of the screen.
2. Type: `screenshot file --fullpage`
3. You will be asked for a location to sav your screenshot in .png format (e.g. `file.png`).

You can also omit the file name if you don't want the image to be saved and rather send it to the clipboard: - `screenshot --fullpage --clipboard`

Type `screenshot help` to see more interesting options.

Comment: I can't take screenshot of big sized iframed google maps. It says [Exception... "Failure", etc, etc

Answer (score 0):

The [Firefox source docs](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/taking_screenshots/index.html) tell how to take a screenshot with the developer tools

**Using the screenshot icon**

> By default, the screenshot icon is not enabled. To enable it:
>
> ```
> visit the Settings page
>
> find the section labeled “Available Toolbox Buttons”
>
> check the box labeled “Take a screenshot of the entire page”.
> ```

**Using the screenshot command**

> Type :screenshot in the Web Console to create a screenshot of the
> current page. By default, the image file will be named Screen Shot
> yyy-mm-dd at hh.mm.ss.png.

Helpful params

| Command | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `--clipboard` | boolean | When present, this parameter will cause the screenshot to be copied to the clipboard. Prevents saving to a file unless you use the --file option to force file writing. |
| `--delay` | number | The number of seconds to delay before taking the screenshot; you can use an integer or floating point number. This is useful if you want to pop open a menu or invoke a hover state for the screenshot. |
| `--dpr` | number | The device pixel ratio to use when taking the screenshot. Values above 1 yield “zoomed-in” images, whereas values below 1 create “zoomed-out” images. |
| `--file` | boolean | When present, the screenshot will be saved to a file, even if other options (e.g. --clipboard) are included. |
| `--filename` | string | The name to use in saving the file. The file should have a “.png” extension. |
| `--fullpage` | boolean | If included, the full webpage will be saved. With this parameter, even the parts of the webpage which are outside the current bounds of the window will be included in the screenshot. When used, "-fullpage” will be appended to the file name. |
| `--selector` | string | A CSS selector that selects a single element on the page. When supplied, only this element and its descendants will be included in the screenshot. |