# Disable `sticky` and `fixed` CSS (for full webpage screenshot)

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Background:** I'm using a tool to take an automated, "full page" screenshot of a webpage. It does this, by scrolling through a web page, taking screenshots, and stitching them together. (no prizes for guessing which tool).

**The problem:** `sticky` and `fixed` html elements ruin the stitching of the images. (essentially every screenshot "snippet" has a banner/footer included in it). See below...

[image]

---

### Question: Is there a way I can instruct a webpage to treat `fixed` and `sticky` css as fixed? (Or negate their effect, by setting up scrolling within a sub element?)

Interim solutions...

**Solution 1:** I can crop the images as it goes (e.g. crop 200px top & bottom). BUT that requires knowing(/assuming) the height of the elements beforehand.

**Solution 2:** Load the website in an `iframe`, and set the iframe height to the height of the inner page. This works perfectly, EXCEPT I run into [`CSP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) issues accessing other websites.

**Assumptions:**

- we can execute Javascript in the browser (e.g. modify dom, css, etc)
- only for Firefox and Chrome
- using native Javascript (no libraries)
- automated (no human involved)

For example, I've attempted setting `fixed` and `sticky` css elements to `relative` (/`absolute`), which works for 90% (but not 100% correct).

```js
var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i++) {
    const pos = window.getComputedStyle(elems[i],null).getPropertyValue('position')
    if (pos == 'sticky' || pos == 'fixed') {
        elems[i].style = "position:relative !important;"
    }
}
```

I'm using the following page for testing: https://digitalocean.com/pricing/

### **Update:** I'd be happy with making the sticky/fixed objects transparent. (Note to self: investigate)

**Similar (but different) questions:**

1. [Capture full webpage screenshot in selenium that has sticky header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52720450/capture-full-webpage-screenshot-in-selenium-that-has-sticky-header) - suggests using other library and aforementioned (discounted) suggested solutions
2. [Take full localhost webpage screenshot (Firefox, Windows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23742901/take-full-localhost-webpage-screenshot-firefox-windows) - manual solution
3. [Full WebPage screenshot using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35339096/full-webpage-screenshot-using-javascript) - suggested solution is to use html2canvas library

Comment: Wrong tool? https://www.utilitylog.com/full-page-screenshot-chrome/ The assumptions are not clear. Do you have to be able to automate this?

Comment: Just an idea, as far as I remember, sticky elements must have either a top, left... attribute. If you could just remove those, sticky will not be sticky anymore.

Comment: @Capsule - yes, automating the solution (fyi using `selenium-webdriver`)

Comment: @djnose - No luck, same effect as setting `position:relative;` - thanks though!

Comment: @NickGrealy thats a pitty :(. What is the effect? Did you check if they are really removed? (like all, bottom, top, left, right)

Comment: @djnose - using `elems[i].style = "top:auto !important;left:auto !important;right:auto !important;bottom:auto !important;"`, the `position:fixed;` still scrolls with the window (in Chrome). (I assume it worked for sticky though). Give it a go... -> https://digitalocean.com/pricing/

Comment: @NickGrealy, a bit hardcore, but that works for me :D `var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i++) {
    const pos = window.getComputedStyle(elems[i],null).getPropertyValue('position')
    if (pos == 'sticky' || pos == 'fixed') {
        elems[i].style = "display:none !important"
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

For `fixed` element you can rely on `transform` or `filter` to change the containing block and disable the fixed behavior (explained here: [CSS-Filter on parent breaks child positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52937708/8620333))

Here is a basic example. Generally we need to apply this to `body`.

```css
.fixed {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background:red;
  height:56px;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  height:220vh;
  filter:blur(0); /* OR transform:translate(0) */
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed"></div>
```

Of course, the trick is to apply a *null* filter or transform to avoid any visual change.

---

For `sticky` element you need to consider the overflow property to disable the effect. Here it is a bit tricky as it will depend on the HTML but in most of the case you need to apply `overflow` with a value other than `visible` on the parent element (Full details here: [What are `scrolling boxes`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55592104/8620333))

Here is a basic example:

```css
.fixed {
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  background:red;
  height:56px;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  height:220vh;
  overflow:auto;
}
html {
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed"></div>
```

The above example is a bit trick because we also face the `overflow` propagation from `body` to `html` that's why I need to explicitely set `overflow` for HTML too or it won't work.

Here is another example with a container other than the body:

```css
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 56px;
}

.container {
  height: 220vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sticky"></div>
</div>
```